# Time in different countries

Tags: java, datetime

I have made a game in Java with a server and a client. The client calculates the progress of player levels. During this it gets from the server when the last update was. Then it looks at what the time difference is. Then level += time difference. But the client can just set its own time 2 ours or so later and than level += 2.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Handling time zones? Preventing cheating?

Comment: Problem:  trusting client data.  Solution:  don't trust client data.  It seems like you're doing that though; you don't make mention of using the client's local time.  Are you doing that, or pulling the time stamp from the server?

Answer (score 1):

This is best solved that way that all times are communicated and stored in UTC.
(Usually a long value: number of seconds or milliseconds from 1.1. 1970, also known as Unix Time).

On Java you get this time with

```
long utcMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Store and communicate that value. caluclate differences with that.

To avoid cheating in the game, you can always use the servers time.

Comment: Thanx but that is what i used (System.currentTimeMillis()). And when the user changes his time that changes too. I will ask my question better: How can i use the time on the server instead of the time of the client.

Comment: @emillio5: Presumably, the server keesp track of how long the client is "playing". So, it can calculate the level accurately. Let the client get the level from the server at appropriate points or intervals.